# Slickgrid checkbox editor issue with inline search

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I have one slickgrid witch checkbox editor and saving the edited value.
I am facing problem when using inline search before editing, because the edited value getting saved for rowindex 0  always not in intended row.

```
ID  checkBoxCol
----------------
1     true

2     true

3     true
```

After inline search in deptID=3, table will be like

```
ID  checkboxCol
----------
3      true
```

Here I have edited column value to 'false', but while saving the value will be like below:

```
ID  checkBoxCol
----------
1       false

2       true 

3       true
```

Please help me on this, to get correct edited value of checkbox editor while applying inline search.
Please let me know for more information

Comment: hey, could you please share the code, as to what have you achieved till now? that would be really helpful.

Comment: Shivi, this seems to be default behavior if slickgrid to save data. For other editor its working fine but not for checkbox editor. If you can have a look into CheckboxEditor, then you can get idea.